# After Installing "Unity Tweak Tool", Every time I use the launcher, the system logout!

Tags: 14.04, unity, unity-tweak-tool

as i said, when i click any icon in the launcher it causes system logout, and close all apps that i was opened, without any warning.

This happens when i try to switch between windows using the launcher

Is there a setting that cause that, or this happens to any one else ?